# Carrierwave, Rails 4; Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - identify)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I'm moving to Rails4.  In my uploader, I have the following:

```
  version :thumb do
     process :resize_to_fill => [200, 200]
  end
```

Which now causes the following error: "Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - identify)"

The error goes away when I comment out the code, but of course now I don't have a thumbnail.  Any ideas as to what is causing this?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of carrierwave?

Answer (score 20):

Reinstalling imagemagick fixed the problem.

Comment: I had a similar problem as well as some new version were not creating. I tried to remove carrierwave cache, cache id and did lots of thing but nothing works for me....finally reinstalling imagemagick worked for all of my problem.  Thanks a lot @pickwick .... man you saved my time...

Answer (score 0):

If you update imagemagick and have the "Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - identify)" issue. Try to update the "mini_magick" and "rmagick" gem.