# Errno::ENOENT in ArtsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I am a ruby and RoR newbie with a project that was working fine on my local machine. I git pushed and then pulled in onto another machine and now I get this error heading

```
Errno::ENOENT in ArtsController#create
Extracted source (around line #29):

 27 # POST /arts.json
 28 def create
 29   @art = Art.new(art_params)
 30
 31   respond_to do |format|
 32     if @art.save
```

Here is the full trace:

```
subexec (0.2.3) lib/subexec.rb:71:in `spawn'
subexec (0.2.3) lib/subexec.rb:71:in `spawn'
subexec (0.2.3) lib/subexec.rb:55:in `run!'
subexec (0.2.3) lib/subexec.rb:41:in `run'
mini_magick (3.5.0) lib/mini_magick.rb:410:in `run'
mini_magick (3.5.0) lib/mini_magick.rb:404:in `run_command'
mini_magick (3.5.0) lib/mini_magick.rb:201:in `valid?'
mini_magick (3.5.0) lib/mini_magick.rb:166:in `create'
mini_magick (3.5.0) lib/mini_magick.rb:76:in `read'
mini_magick (3.5.0) lib/mini_magick.rb:137:in `block in open'
mini_magick (3.5.0) lib/mini_magick.rb:136:in `open'
mini_magick (3.5.0) lib/mini_magick.rb:136:in `open'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/processing/mini_magick.rb:260:in `manipulate!'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/processing/mini_magick.rb:176:in `resize_to_fill'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:85:in `block in process!'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:81:in `each'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:81:in `process!'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in with_callbacks'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `each'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `with_callbacks'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:122:in `cache!'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:273:in `block in cache_versions!'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:258:in `each'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:258:in `cache_versions!'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in with_callbacks'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `each'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `with_callbacks'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:122:in `cache!'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:327:in `cache'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:179:in `picture='
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:38:in `picture='
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:42:in `public_send'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:42:in `_assign_attribute'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:29:in `block in assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:23:in `each'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:23:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/core.rb:460:in `init_attributes'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/core.rb:185:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
app/controllers/arts_controller.rb:29:in `create'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run__3371811400870705869__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__903416006247958899__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/oz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/oz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/oz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Maybe you don't have directory where you're trying to save on that second machine?

Comment: but the problem is in line 29 with art_params. Also, I believe art.save is just a boolean that shows whether the content was successfully uploaded with all the required info fields.

Comment: Indeed, but `Errno::ENOENT` resembles filesystem error, `new` creates object only in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out the code or re-installing seems to fix the problem as described here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391271/carrierwave-rails-4-errnoenoent-no-such-file-or-directory-identify
```