# rake db:setup -> rake aborted! Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - identify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rake, minimagick

Im trying to get setup on an existing ruby on rails project, but am getting hung up on the postgres db setup.  I used RVM to set up the project with ruby 2.1.2.  Installed the pg gem with homebrew using the following command:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg_config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
```

My database.yml file looks like this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: myusername
  password: 

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_test
  pool: 5
  username: myusername
  password:
```

I bundle installed all my gems.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'activerecord-session_store'

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

# authentication using Devise (email / password) and omniauth (oauth)
gem "devise", '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'devise_invitable', '~> 1.3.0'
gem "beta_invites", :github=>'danman01/beta_invites'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', git: 'git://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.git'
gem "omniauth-soundcloud"
# validation for emails
gem 'valid_email'


# set env variables within config/application.yml
gem "figaro"

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

# User roles. ex: User.first.add_role!("admin")
gem "easy_roles"

# manage meta tags
gem "meta-tags", :require => "meta_tags"

# error notification. TODO - setup https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification
gem 'exception_notification', git: "git://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification.git"

# nice rails urls for seo and readability
gem "friendly_id", '~> 5.0.0'

# use foreman start to startup multiple processes at once (i.e. rails and delayed job queue)
gem "foreman"

gem "nokogiri", '~> 1.6.3'

# pagination
gem "kaminari"

# admin panel, available at /admin
gem "rails_admin"

# cron scheduling for the server. See config/schedule
gem 'whenever', :require =>false

# tool to party
gem 'httparty'

gem 'simple_form'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'

# app permissions. set in models/ability.rb
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.8'

# caching
gem 'dalli'

# activity feed
gem 'public_activity'

# image upload
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave-aws'
gem 'mini_magick'

gem "sidekiq"
gem 'sinatra', require: false
gem 'slim'
# tree structure
gem "ancestry"

# more organized db seeds
gem "seedbank"

# run code safely in migrations
gem 'migration_data'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development do

  # better formatting of errors
  gem "better_errors"
  # do not output so much about assets to console
  gem "quiet_assets"
  # debugging tool: https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller
  gem "binding_of_caller"
  gem "tracer_bullets"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem "faker"
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
  gem "pry-rails"
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  # preload rails app to speed things up
  gem "spring"
  gem "spring-commands-rspec"
  # auto run things
  gem "guard"
  gem "guard-rspec", require: false
  gem 'rb-fsevent' if `uname` =~ /Darwin/
  gem 'thin' # or thin


end

group :development, :production do
  gem 'cohort_me'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem "launchy"
  gem "database_cleaner"
end

# Rails view utilities

# use country-select with priority countries like: country_select("user", "country_name", [ "United Kingdom", "France", "Germany" ])
gem 'country-select'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'

# random comment

# Use Capistrano for deployment

gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1'
gem 'capistrano', '~>3.1'
gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.2'
gem 'capistrano-rvm'
gem 'capistrano-sidekiq', github: 'seuros/capistrano-sidekiq'#
# gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
# ruby '2.1.1'
gem 'rb-fsevent'
```

I started the postgres server manually using:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

The logfile outputs this:

```
ERROR:  database "myapp_development" already exists
STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE "musictown_development" ENCODING = 'unicode'
ERROR:  database "myapp_test" already exists
STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE "musictown_test" ENCODING = 'unicode'
```

Alternatively i used the postgresapp to start the server.

And when I run rake db:setup I get this:

```
myapp_development already exists
myapp_test already exists
```

It creates a bunch of tables and indexes then when it gets here it stops:

```
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0154s
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - identify
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/subexec-0.2.3/lib/subexec.rb:71:in `spawn'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/subexec-0.2.3/lib/subexec.rb:71:in `spawn'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/subexec-0.2.3/lib/subexec.rb:55:in `run!'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/subexec-0.2.3/lib/subexec.rb:41:in `run'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/mini_magick-3.8.0/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:405:in `run'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/mini_magick-3.8.0/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:399:in `run_command'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/mini_magick-3.8.0/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:184:in `valid?'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/mini_magick-3.8.0/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:140:in `create'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/mini_magick-3.8.0/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:47:in `read'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/mini_magick-3.8.0/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:111:in `block in open'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/mini_magick-3.8.0/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:110:in `open'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/mini_magick-3.8.0/lib/mini_magick/image.rb:110:in `open'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/processing/mini_magick.rb:260:in `manipulate!'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/processing/mini_magick.rb:153:in `resize_to_fit'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:84:in `block in process!'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:76:in `each'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:76:in `process!'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in with_callbacks'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `each'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `with_callbacks'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:122:in `cache!'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:329:in `cache'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:163:in `image='
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:39:in `image='
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:42:in `public_send'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:42:in `_assign_attribute'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:29:in `block in assign_attributes'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:23:in `each'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:23:in `assign_attributes'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/core.rb:460:in `init_attributes'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/core.rb:185:in `initialize'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:36:in `create'
/Users/myusername/Documents/MusicTown/musictown/db/seeds.rb:9:in `block in define_seed_task'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/seedbank-0.3.0/lib/seedbank/dsl.rb:24:in `module_eval'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/seedbank-0.3.0/lib/seedbank/dsl.rb:24:in `block in define_seed_task'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:seed => db:seed:common => db:seed:original
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Maybe theres something wrong with one of the gems in the gemfile?

This question is sorta similar: [Carrierwave, Rails 4; Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - identify)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391271/carrierwave-rails-4-errnoenoent-no-such-file-or-directory-identify).  Maybe some gem is the wrong version?

Comment: The problem isn't PostgreSQL, the problem is minimagick through CarrierWave. `identify` is part of ImageMagick and it seems that you don't have it in your `PATH`.

Comment: hey @muistooshort thanks for the response.  I am still a bit unclear about what I am supposed to do.  What path am I supposed to add to my bash_profile?

Comment: `identify` is part of ImageMagick so you need to have the ImageMagick CLI tools installed and where ever they are needs to be in your `PATH`. I don't use CarrierWave or minimagick so I'm making some guesses here, presumably the documentation for those gems would cover all this stuff.

Comment: thanks @muistooshort I installed ImageMagick CLI tools: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php, Mac OS Binary Release, installing with MacPorts, and that added the paths to my .bash_profile.  so now the rake db:setup command is able to find ImageMagick

Comment: @muistooshort I wouldn't have gotten it without your comment, so thanks again.  I will mark it as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, install ImageMagick CLI tools from here: [imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php), Mac OS Binary Release.  Installing with MacPorts, which adds the paths to my .bash_profile file. Now rake db:setup command is able to find ImageMagick, and works.